# Move or copy SSL certificates from broken windows server

Tags: iis, ssl, certificate

Yesterday we had a major problem with our windows 2003 webserver and we had to move all our sites to a new machine. There were a couple of sites that used a SSL certificate and we cannot export these because the we cannot start windows on the broken machine.

Is there a way to get these certificates to work on the other server? I have access to the hard drive of the broken server. I may have to mention that the new server is on windows 2008 r2.

Comment: Question belongs on serverfault.com

Comment: Agreed, this should be migrated to ServerFault.